# Drop Down List first row as Empty

Tags: c#

I need code for first row of drop down to be empty, below is the current code i am using

```
string queryString = "select College_Name from Colleges";
string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                         .ConnectionStrings["ConnDBForum"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
connection.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
ad.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
    DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "College_Name";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "College_Name";
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
connection.Close();
```

Can any one please help me on this ?

Comment: Move the `Items.Insert` to after the `DataBind()` call.

Comment: Travis is right. And you can use the `.Add()` Method instead of `.Insert()` because two lines before you check if contains anything.

Comment: please read documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the insert after the bind or you can add the empty row to the datatable using `dt.Rows.InsertAt` ans you won't need `DropDownList2.Items.Insert`.

```
DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
DropDownList2.DataTextField = "College_Name";
DropDownList2.DataValueField = "College_Name";
DropDownList2.DataBind();
DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
```

Comment: See my comment above. Could you change it to `Add`? Just to provide clear code

Comment: You can't use Add to insert at the 0th index.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, you're right. Didn't rethink it with `Insert` in the last line. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach loop to add each item to the drop down list, and if it is the first item, add a blank.

```
 bool firstItem = true;
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
     if (firstItem)
        comboBox1.Items.Add("");

     firstItem = false;

     comboBox1.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
 }
```